# How to make this button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, submit

How to submit form elements with jQuery datatables

I have the following code (for datatable). Now i need to make the button to activate this code. I tried but don't now how to make this button. Can someone help?

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form').submit( function() {
    var sData = oTable.$('input').serialize();
    alert( "The following data submitted to the server: \n\n"+sData );
        return false;
    } );

 oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

Comment: `<input type="submit" />` however the form will not submit to the server unless you Ajax it

Comment: Are you trying to make a button to submit the form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes i try to submit a form (datatable is inside this form). 
But when i use input type = "submit" nothing happens. Page just reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default actions of the form submission.

```
$('#form').submit( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Your other code here
});
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**
I just realized you still want the default actions. I'm used to ajax, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Is your `<input type="submit" value="Submit">` inside of the same form? Because this is the correct answer.

Comment: add it in your form and form name must be same as #form

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to execute the function on form submit just make a submit button.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

That will cause the form submit, which is what your javascript is listening for.